# use wcstombs() to convert wchar_t* (containing Unicode) to MBCS (char*) dependent on locale

Tags: unicode

My input is Unicode characters, eg:, "(U+00DB) (U+0081)" (wchar_t*). I use wcstombs to convert this wide char string into char * (MBCS). Since Unicode is already encoded in UTF-8 I am expecting it to return byte by byte copied sequence of Unicode as DB81 char*. But instead I get c3 9b. This is happening on Linux and on windows i get "DB 81" only.

I need to open a file with name DB 81 (as shown in hexdump), but fopen uses char* filename. Thus I have to convert this wchar_t* to MBCS. Please help!!

Comment: "Since Unicode is already encoded in UTF-8" - that is not true in this case. A `wchar_t*`, on any platform, is never encoded as UTF-8. The `wchar_t` type is either 16-bit or 32-bit depending on platform, and thus is encoded as UTF-16 or UTF-32. Converting to MBCS is not the same as converting to UTF-8, unless you are using a UTF-8 locale/codepage. If you want to convert UTF-16/UTF-32 to UTF-8, you should use ICONV, ICU, or other Unicode library to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you want to do is not what you think you should.

fopen(), under any circumstances - cannot handle all possible filenames on your system, because it lacks unicode support.

Please refer to http://www.utf8everywhere.org to see how to do it with _wfopen().